# Cannot export mexFunction: symbol not defined collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, matlab

I using Matlab r2017a,when I using 'mex pq_demo.cpp ' compile the C++ files,It come out the error:

Cannot export mexFunction: symbol not defined
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

My mexFunction is in pq_create.cpp:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]){
    // read the parameters
    // check input
    if( nrhs != 1 || !mxIsNumeric(prhs[0]) )
        mexErrMsgTxt("A unique scalar number with the expected size of the queue is necessary.\n");

    // retrieve the data
    int nelems = 100;
    retrieve_data( prhs[0], nelems );

    // instantiate the priority queue
    MaxHeap<double>* pq = new MaxHeap<double>(nelems);

    // convert the points to double
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
    double* pointer_to_tree = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    pointer_to_tree[0] = (long long) pq;
}
```

So,how can I resolve the error.Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You should include head file `mex.h` first such as `#include mex.h`